# Plot several functions using different colors, including a derivative

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I have a really simple issue with my Python program -- which isn't finished at all. Right now it's doing everything I want, but not how I want.

[image: plot]

There are three things I've been trying to change:

1. all functions are being plotted using the same color, and I'd like the program to automatically switch to a new color when a new function is added to the plot (it will be more than 2, all on the same plot).
2. f(x)'s range is 140. How can I decrease that? Maybe to 20/40.
3. (most important) My code isn't very efficient. `f1` and `derivative` are not associated at all. I declare the function's model in `f1`, but I have to set up everything again in `derivative`. Every time I try to do otherwise I end up having some problem with the `main` function. I'll eventually add more features like integration and whatnot, and if I'm declaring everything from scratch everytime I want to do something with `f1` the program will kinda lose its purpose.

Should I use `x = Symbol('x')` `inside f1`?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')

def f1(a, b, c, d):
    y = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + x*c + d
    return y
    ###yprime = y.diff(x) 
    ###return yprime

def derivative(a, b, c, d):
    y = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + x*c + d
    yprime = y.diff(x)
    return yprime

def factorail(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

###colors = iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ys))))
###for y in ys:
    ###plt.scatter(x, y, color=next(colors))
def main():
    ###colors = itertools.cycle(["r", "b", "g"])
    y = f1(0,1,2,1)
    yp = derivative(0,1,2,1)
    print(y)
    plot(y, yp)
    plot(yp)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have answered the first problem you have.  In general, stackoverflow questions are supposed to ask one thing, that way future people can find the question and the answer they are looking for efficiently.  I highly recommend making this question 3 questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multicolored Plot from SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751999/multicolored-plot-from-sympy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vertical window is set by `ylim` option. I recommend to also use some explicit limits for `x`, the default -10 to 10 is not necessarily best for you. And I do recommend reading [the page on SymPy plotting](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html).

Color is set by `line_color` option. Different colors require different calls to `plot`, but those can be combined. Example:

```
p = plot(y, (x, -5, 5), ylim=(-20, 20), line_color='b', show=False)
p.extend(plot(yp, (x, -5, 5), ylim=(-20, 20), line_color='r', show=False))
p.show()
```

results in

[image: combined]

The function reuse is easy:

```
def derivative(a, b, c, d):
    y = f1(a, b, c, d)
    yprime = y.diff(x)
    return yprime
```

Aside: what happens if we try `line_color=['b', 'r']`, as in `plot(y, yp, ylim=(-20, 20), line_color=['b', 'r'])`? Funny stuff happens:

[image: funny]

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! It worked perfectly.  Just out of curiosity: is there a difference between graphing with matplotlib and sympy, or they are like "two sides of the same coin"? Last thing, how did you get that grid going? I tried using adaptive=False on plot() like on sympy's page, but it didn't work. Do I need to use plot_implicit ?

Comment: SymPy eventually will call a backend plotting library, which is most likely to be matplotlib. But when plotting via SymPy, you do not get involved in things like "how many sample points to use, `np.linspace(a, b, n?)`". The options of `sympy.plot` are quite different from the options that matplotlib offers. As for the grid and grey background, they are due to my environment, which is a [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to get colors that are "far" from each other in a general way.  The 2396745 is pretty arbitrary, and defines how far apart the colors are.  It seems to give me good results.

```
def cmap_ints(i):
    return "#"+hex(((int(i)+1)*2396745)%(256**3))[2:].rjust(6,"0")
```

Usage:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y1 = 3*x + 4
y2 = 2*x - 5
plt.plot(x,y1,c=cmap_ints(1))
plt.plot(x,y2,c=cmap_ints(2))
```

Comment: The OP is not using Matplotlib's plot function.

Comment: @user6655984 this is irrelevant.  The colors produced by the `cmap_ints` function are simple RGB values.  One could use this with basically any graphing system.

Comment: Works fine for me in Google Colab, which is currently using Sympy 1.7.1.

```
p = plot(sin(x),(x,0,2*pi), show=False)
p.extend( plot( sin(2*x), (x,0,2*pi), show=False))
for i in range(0,2) : p[i].line_color = cmap_ints(i)
p.show()
```